# How to describe a dead drunk individual in modern AE?

Tags: phrase-choice

I was wondering if you could tell me which one of the following sentences can be used to describe a dead drunk person in AE:

> - He drank so much that he got blackout drunk.
> - He drank himself into a stupor.
> - He drank himself into oblivion.

Based on several dictionaries, all the above sentences can be used in this sense, but I have no idea if they all sound natural to an AE native these days.

Comment: These phrases are just the tip of the iceberg. There are problably almost as many idiomatic expressions relating to alcohol as there are about sex.

Comment: @JavaLatte thank you for being of the help. But asking this question I was going to request you to help me know the best sentences in this respect. What I find is always based on my dictionaries, but as you are well aware, they do not define every single idiom / expression to be old fashioned or in common use, formality or informality, geographical differences etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the first one to

> He drank so much that he blacked out.

That both avoids using the same word "drink" twice (albeit in different forms), and avoids the (to me) unnatural adjective "blackout".

The other two are fine, although the second one (again, to me) is not quite as severe as the other two. They talk about the man going unconscious, the second only talks about a stupor - imagine a person sitting in the corner, staring at nothing.

Comment: Agreed,  blackout is a noun. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blackout?q=Blackout

Comment: @Jav So  is *office* in *office building.* The suggested sentence may be unusual, even novel, but it's not wrong. Maybe it's brilliant. If black things can be brilliant.

Comment: Hmm. "Blackout drunk" might also indicate a condition where the drunk is walking, talking, and getting into trouble; but the next day the hungover ex-drunk doesn't remember anything he did - he has a blackout over that time period. That's again different from "oblivion" and "stupor".

Comment: I don't mean to suggest that the sentence is what the OP wants. They ask if it's *natural,* and certainly in at least some sense it's not. But if a good novelist or poet wrote *She got blackout drunk* in a suitable context, it might communicate *extremely drunk* very effectively.